# QtGui.QTextEdit set line color baced on what text the line contains

Tags: python, pyqt

It's my first time using stackoverflow to find an answer, to my problems.
I'm using a QtGui.QTextEdit to display text similar to below and would like to change the color of the text on some lines based on if they contain certain text.

lines that start with --[ will be blue and lines that contain [ERROR] would be red.
I currently have something like the following,

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import sys

class Log(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, path=None, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.taskLog = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.taskLog.setLineWrapMode(False)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.taskLog)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        log = open("/net/test.log", 'r')
        self.taskLog.setText(log.read())
        log.close()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
wnd = Log()
wnd.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The text looks something like this at the moment

```
--[ Begin 
this is a test

[ERROR] this test failed.

--[ Command returned exit code 1
```

Hopefully you all will be able to help me work this out a lot faster that, trying to work it out my self.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html). Here's a simple demo:

[image: screenshot]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

sample = """
--[ Begin
this is a test

[ERROR] this test failed.

--[ Command returned exit code 1
"""

class Highlighter(QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Highlighter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.sectionFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        self.sectionFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        self.errorFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        self.errorFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.red)

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        # uncomment this line for Python2
        # text = unicode(text)
        if text.startswith('--['):
            self.setFormat(0, len(text), self.sectionFormat)
        elif text.startswith('[ERROR]'):
            self.setFormat(0, len(text), self.errorFormat)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.editor = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.highlighter = Highlighter(self.editor.document())
        self.editor.setText(sample)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.editor)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 150, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi ekhumoro,

This looks like a simple way to do it, like what I'm looking for, but getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                          
  File "test.py", line 21, in highlightBlock                                
    if text.startswith('--['):                                              
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: have tried replacing the startswith with a regular expression Like so:

def highlightBlock(self, text):
 import re
 begin = re.compile(r'^--[')
 error = re.compile(r'^[ERROR]')
 if begin.search(text) is not None:
  self.setFormat(0, len(text), self.sectionFormat)
 elif error.search(text) is not None:
  self.setFormat(0, len(text), self.errorFormat)

Comment: but thats giving me the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in highlightBlock
    begin = re.compile(r'^--[')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression

Comment: got it just used a regular expression instead of startswith, Thanks

Comment: @Mark. The error happens because you're using Python2. There's no need to use a regular expression - you can just convert the `QString` to a python string using the `unicode` function (I've updated my code example). Alternatively, you could use `text.startsWith` (note the uppercase "W"), which uses the corresponding `QString` method. This would be the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using HTML format

```
textEdit.setHtml(text);
```

But even better, the QSyntaxHighlighter class:

Doc : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html

Python Exemple : https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Python%20syntax%20highlighting

Here an exemple with a code editor.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QRegExp
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor, QTextCharFormat, QFont, QSyntaxHighlighter

def format(color, style=''):
    """Return a QTextCharFormat with the given attributes.
    """
    _color = QColor()
    _color.setNamedColor(color)

    _format = QTextCharFormat()
    _format.setForeground(_color)
    if 'bold' in style:
        _format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
    if 'italic' in style:
        _format.setFontItalic(True)

    return _format


# Syntax styles that can be shared by all languages
STYLES = {
    'keyword': format('blue'),
    'operator': format('red'),
    'brace': format('darkGray'),
    'defclass': format('black', 'bold'),
    'string': format('magenta'),
    'string2': format('darkMagenta'),
    'comment': format('darkGreen', 'italic'),
    'self': format('black', 'italic'),
    'numbers': format('brown'),
}


class PythonHighlighter (QSyntaxHighlighter):
    """Syntax highlighter for the Python language.
    """
    # Python keywords
    keywords = [
        'and', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def',
        'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally',
        'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in',
        'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print',
        'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'yield',
        'None', 'True', 'False',
    ]

    # Python operators
    operators = [
        '=',
        # Comparison
        '==', '!=', '<', '<=', '>', '>=',
        # Arithmetic
        '\+', '-', '\*', '/', '//', '\%', '\*\*',
        # In-place
        '\+=', '-=', '\*=', '/=', '\%=',
        # Bitwise
        '\^', '\|', '\&', '\~', '>>', '<<',
    ]

    # Python braces
    braces = [
        '\{', '\}', '\(', '\)', '\[', '\]',
    ]
    def __init__(self, document):
        QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__(self, document)

        # Multi-line strings (expression, flag, style)
        # FIXME: The triple-quotes in these two lines will mess up the
        # syntax highlighting from this point onward
        self.tri_single = (QRegExp("'''"), 1, STYLES['string2'])
        self.tri_double = (QRegExp('"""'), 2, STYLES['string2'])

        rules = []

        # Keyword, operator, and brace rules
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % w, 0, STYLES['keyword'])
            for w in PythonHighlighter.keywords]
        rules += [(r'%s' % o, 0, STYLES['operator'])
            for o in PythonHighlighter.operators]
        rules += [(r'%s' % b, 0, STYLES['brace'])
            for b in PythonHighlighter.braces]

        # All other rules
        rules += [
            # 'self'
            (r'\bself\b', 0, STYLES['self']),

            # Double-quoted string, possibly containing escape sequences
            (r'"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"', 0, STYLES['string']),
            # Single-quoted string, possibly containing escape sequences
            (r"'[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'", 0, STYLES['string']),

            # 'def' followed by an identifier
            (r'\bdef\b\s*(\w+)', 1, STYLES['defclass']),
            # 'class' followed by an identifier
            (r'\bclass\b\s*(\w+)', 1, STYLES['defclass']),

            # From '#' until a newline
            (r'#[^\n]*', 0, STYLES['comment']),

            # Numeric literals
            (r'\b[+-]?[0-9]+[lL]?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
            (r'\b[+-]?0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+[lL]?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
            (r'\b[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
        ]

        # Build a QRegExp for each pattern
        self.rules = [(QRegExp(pat), index, fmt)
            for (pat, index, fmt) in rules]


    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        """Apply syntax highlighting to the given block of text.
        """
        # Do other syntax formatting
        for expression, nth, format in self.rules:
            index = expression.indexIn(text, 0)

            while index >= 0:
                # We actually want the index of the nth match
                index = expression.pos(nth)
                length = expression.cap(nth).length()
                self.setFormat(index, length, format)
                index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)

        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)

        # Do multi-line strings
        in_multiline = self.match_multiline(text, *self.tri_single)
        if not in_multiline:
            in_multiline = self.match_multiline(text, *self.tri_double)


    def match_multiline(self, text, delimiter, in_state, style):
        """Do highlighting of multi-line strings. ``delimiter`` should be a
        ``QRegExp`` for triple-single-quotes or triple-double-quotes, and
        ``in_state`` should be a unique integer to represent the corresponding
        state changes when inside those strings. Returns True if we're still
        inside a multi-line string when this function is finished.
        """
        # If inside triple-single quotes, start at 0
        if self.previousBlockState() == in_state:
            start = 0
            add = 0
        # Otherwise, look for the delimiter on this line
        else:
            start = delimiter.indexIn(text)
            # Move past this match
            add = delimiter.matchedLength()

        # As long as there's a delimiter match on this line...
        while start >= 0:
            # Look for the ending delimiter
            end = delimiter.indexIn(text, start + add)
            # Ending delimiter on this line?
            if end >= add:
                length = end - start + add + delimiter.matchedLength()
                self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
            # No; multi-line string
            else:
                self.setCurrentBlockState(in_state)
                length = text.length() - start + add
            # Apply formatting
            self.setFormat(start, length, style)
            # Look for the next match
            start = delimiter.indexIn(text, start + length)

        # Return True if still inside a multi-line string, False otherwise
        if self.currentBlockState() == in_state:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```