# Validate input text in a QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, validation, pyqt, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

I am writing a simple editor program. How can I check the input text? For example, when the input contains "print", re-format it (color, bold, etc). How to check it continuously?

```
def recognizer(self):
    while True:
        if "word" in self.plainTextEdit.toplainText :
            print("True")
```

Comment: explain yourself better, and give a better example.

Comment: It sounds like you may want a [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html). Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40155268/984421.