# How to make a Colored QTextEdit in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

Suppose i have a text box "QTextEdit" then when i type a statement like,
!!
**nikhil a python programmer**

The text box should have nikhil in green text and python in Yellow Highlighted.
Just as out Python IDLE has color for each keywords, something like that!

I tried manipulating HTML content in QTextEdit, no luck with it!

Fellow Programmer if you can help me then please help me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: @MalloyDelacroix except that its about textEdit not textbrowser.

Comment: QTextBrowser inherits the methods used in that answer from QTextEdit.

Comment: Ok Let me try it out.

Comment: @Nikhil. It sounds like you want some kind of syntax highlighting. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40155268/984421) for a simple example.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for this solution!